# Make bash dos-eol tolerant

Tags: bash, shell-script, newlines

It happens when I want to compile some Linux kernel that somehow I end up with such messages:

```
.../kernel-source/scripts/mkmakefile: line 5: $'\r': command not found
```

That is because the file is with DOS-EOL instead of the normal one. I usually am able to patch those problematic files with a `dos2unix`, but in that case, the `mkmakefile` file is generated by some other script (using Yocto Linux Framework, but I had the same problem with Android build process).

I know there is a `igncr` bash option for CygWin, but nothing on Linux bash.

Is there a way/option to tell bash to just ignore `\r` characters (i.e. have `\r\n` equivalent to `\n`)?

EDIT:
The errors appear on the first blank lines between the shebang and the first executable line (blank lines between comments).

The Yocto logs (which is actually Petalinux, Xilinx' Yocto-based framework) shows:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate
DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished
DEBUG: Executing python function check_oldest_kernel
DEBUG: Python function check_oldest_kernel finished
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
NOTE: make HOSTCC=gcc  HOSTCPP=gcc  -E -C .../project/build/tmp/work-shared/plnx_arm/kernel-source O=.../project/build/tmp/work/plnx_arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-xlnx/4.9-xilinx-v2017.4+gitAUTOINC+b450e900fd-r0/linux-plnx_arm-standard-build oldnoconfig
NOTE: make HOSTCC=gcc  HOSTCPP=gcc  -E -C .../project/build/tmp/work-shared/plnx_arm/kernel-source O=.../project/build/tmp/work/plnx_arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-xlnx/4.9-xilinx-v2017.4+gitAUTOINC+b450e900fd-r0/linux-plnx_arm-standard-build oldconfig
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
make: Entering directory '.../project/build/tmp/work-shared/plnx_arm/kernel-source'
make[1]: Entering directory '.../project/build/tmp/work/plnx_arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-xlnx/4.9-xilinx-v2017.4+gitAUTOINC+b450e900fd-r0/linux-plnx_arm-standard-build'
.../project/build/tmp/work-shared/plnx_arm/kernel-source/scripts/mkmakefile: line 5: $'\r': command not found
.../project/build/tmp/work-shared/plnx_arm/kernel-source/scripts/mkmakefile: line 11: $'\r': command not found
.../project/build/tmp/work-shared/plnx_arm/kernel-source/scripts/mkmakefile: line 12: $'\r': command not found
.../project/build/tmp/work-shared/plnx_arm/kernel-source/scripts/mkmakefile: line 52: warning: here-document at line 24 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
.../project/build/tmp/work-shared/plnx_arm/kernel-source/scripts/mkmakefile: line 53: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make[1]: *** [.../project/build/tmp/work-shared/plnx_arm/kernel-source/Makefile:461: outputmakefile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '.../project/build/tmp/work/plnx_arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/linux-xlnx/4.9-xilinx-v2017.4+gitAUTOINC+b450e900fd-r0/linux-plnx_arm-standard-build'
make: *** [Makefile:150: sub-make] Error 2
```

Line 53 is a single `EOF` marker, without any newline (from `cat << EOF > Makefile`)

I guess the last line in the generated script is `EOF^M`, which does not match the expected `EOF` (without the `\r`/`^M`).

Comment: Where does the files with just `\r` come from? Yocto should not generate files with `\r` or ` \r\n` instead of `\n`, if it does, there is something wrong with Yocto.

Comment: @Alexander I edited with the logs. It seems the `\r` is not the root problem, as I originally suspected. Which is not too helpful for me though...

Comment: You could probably patch Bash to drop any carriage returns on input though. If cygwin has that feature, they are likely to have a code snippet you could borrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way/option to tell bash to just ignore `\r` characters (i.e. have `\r\n` equivalent to `\n`).

Files can be stored in the file system with either file ending, and bash has no issue with this.

Comment: Thanks, I did run some tests and it seems bash indeed doesn't care much. The source of my problem is probably somewhere else...

Comment: Yocto can be pretty opaque and secretive about where the errors really lie, if it's any comfort.

Comment: *bash has no issue with this* but still, when I run `unix2dos working.sh`, it stops working with `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter`... But the rest of the file can have `\r\n` without any warning, *except* on blank lines (the script shows the `$'\r': command not found` but proceeds with the rest of the script).

Comment: It seems the root cause was `autocrlf` in `git`, that might have been used somewhere in Petalinux/Yocto. `git config --global core.autocrlf input` solved it, as stated in my answer below. However, your answer remains correct to my original question "*Can we make bash eol tolerant*"; it's just my question that was wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem seems to be caused by git being used internally by the build process. Under Linux, make sure to set the `autocrlf` to `input`:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

The build worked fine after that.